# Bug in chrome hover when window.open() called.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I believe there's a bug in chrome for hovering when a new window is opened.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>

#outter {
   height:30px;
   width:30px;
   background-color:grey;
   position:relative;
}

#outter:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
   background-color:red;
}

#menuBox {
   position:absolute;
   top:100%;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid black;
   display:none;
}

.menuItem {
   height:20px;
}

.menuItem:hover {
   background-color:grey;
}

</style>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#outter").on("click",function() {
      $("#menuBox").toggle();
});

$(".menuItem").on("click",function() {
   window.open(
       "http://www.google.com",
       "",
      "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=100,height=100,top=100,left=100");
   });

});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="outter">

   <div id="menuBox">
      <div class="menuItem">1</div>
      <div class="menuItem">2</div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

To reproduce:

1. Select square to open container
2. select menu item
3. close open window.
4. select square again

** BUG encountered- as you can see the menu item is highlighted as if it were hovered **

Can someone please tell me if they are getting this with other versions of chrome too?

I'm running Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) on Mac OsX

Comment: Happens for me too in Chrome on Mac. Firefox is fine - the element loses hover state when the new window opens. It does seem to be a bug. Here's a working fiddle I tested with: https://jsfiddle.net/x3sb20us/

Comment: Thanks Rory, I guess I'll log it... Although it seems minor (maybe it is) it makes me menus looks unprofessional in chrome...

Comment: Although I just tried in Chrome on windows and it worked fine

Comment: What Mac OS are you using? I checked it on Mac Sierra and Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) and it works for me.

Comment: Hi Rahi oh that's interesting :S I'm running 10.9.5 not sure what code name that is... Sierra is 10.12 maybe it's a mac windowing issue not Chrome?

Comment: Rory what mac Os are you running?

Comment: I'm using Sierra 10.12.3